# Videos sent by android in bytes are not recieved by apache server..

Tags: android, python, django, apache

I am using django==1.11 on the backend I am using apache2 server. I am receiving videos in bytes sent by android but I am getting an error "[wsgi:error] [pid 21270] The joined path is located outside of the base path component (/var/www)"

Whereas when running the same server on port 8000 its working fine.. 
Even images with size more that 1 MB are not received by apache..
Can the issue be of Firewall or apache has some size limit issues??
Any suggestion as what might be the problem..

Comment: What was the other port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked.. Actually the error was our files were not static it had to be in media.. N our media folder was inside static which gave an error when run on apache server... The error was solved when I took the media folder outside static...